# Gremlin.Net, how to do a Left Outer join?

Tags: gremlin, gremlinnet

I try to understand how to create a request similar to a left outer join in Gremlin.Net.

I have this data :

```
        using (GremlinClient client = new GremlinClient(new GremlinServer("localhost", 8182)))
        {
            g = AnonymousTraversalSource.Traversal().WithRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection(client));
            g.V().Drop().Iterate();

            var Bob = g.AddV("Person").Property("name", "Bob").ToList()[0];
            var John = g.AddV("Person").Property("name", "John").ToList()[0];
            var Ringo = g.AddV("Person").Property("name", "Ringo").ToList()[0];

            var group1 = g.AddV("Group").Property("name", "Group1").ToList()[0];
            g.V(group1.Id).AddE("in").To(Bob).Iterate();
            g.V(group1.Id).AddE("in").To(John).Iterate();
            g.V(group1.Id).AddE("in").To(Ringo).Iterate();

            var group2 = g.AddV("Group").Property("name", "Group2").ToList()[0];
            g.V(group2.Id).AddE("in").To(Bob).Iterate();
```

So I have two groups : G1 (with Bob, John, Ringo) and G2 with only Bob. And I want to find the list of groups that don't have a subgroup. How  can I do ?

The response I search is : G2, as it is the only group with no subgroup (G1 have G2 as a sub group)

Thanks to help me to understand the way Gremlin.Net works!

Comment: Could you please clarify what the output is that you want to have the query return? Do you want to find the members of G1 not in G2 or something else? Left Outer Join would imply all of G1 plus some part of G2 but you mention that you are looking for groups that do not have a sub group so perhaps you want the answer to be John and Ringo but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, I'm still not sure what you mean by "sub group" in the sample data you provided, neither of the groups are connected.

Comment: Yes, G1 and G2 are not connected, except by their content.